# transfer data to higher dimension

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to move my data to higher dimension. I need every column transform from x to exp(x^2) and for each pair of x1 and x2 of column cl1 and col 2 I need a new column with value exp(e^{-2xy}). here is a small example :(I have more column in my data set)

```
     col1.    col2.    col3. 
       2      3        4
```

out put

```
     col1.    col2.    col3.      col(1,2)  col(2,3)  col(1,3)
    exp(4)    exp(9)   exp(16)    exp(-12).  exp(-24)  exp(-16)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have R-native data (like a `data.frame`) instead of this, for both input and expect-output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep things interesting, I'll increase your data by a row so that I don't get sloppy :-)

Your row is first, verify with that.

```r
dat <- data.frame(col1=2:3, col2=3:4, col3=4:5)
```

I'll leave out the `exp()` in the initial run, since your validation does not do the actual calculation.

The first problem is straight-forward:

```r
lapply(dat, function(a) (a^2))
# $col1
# [1] 4 9
# $col2
# [1]  9 16
# $col3
# [1] 16 25
```

The second takes a little more work, but not much:

```r
combinations <- combn(3, 2)
combnames <- apply(combinations, 2, paste, collapse = "_")
setNames(data.frame(apply(combinations, 2, function(i) -2 * dat[,i[1]] * dat[,i[2]])),
         combnames)
#   1_2 1_3 2_3
# 1 -12 -16 -24
# 2 -24 -30 -40
```

From here, it's just `cbind`ing things together. I'm including `exp()` now, but the use of `exp(e^...)` seems a typo, so I'll infer just `exp()` for the second batch, too.

```r
cbind(
  lapply(dat, function(a) exp(a^2)),
  setNames(data.frame(apply(combinations, 2, function(i) exp(-2 * dat[,i[1]] * dat[,i[2]]))),
           combnames)
)
#         col1        col2        col3          1_2          1_3          2_3
# 1   54.59815    8103.084     8886111 6.144212e-06 1.125352e-07 3.775135e-11
# 2 8103.08393 8886110.521 72004899337 3.775135e-11 9.357623e-14 4.248354e-18
```